# Finding $P$ points among $N$ to approximate a probability density function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization, optimal-transportation

Let $f$ be a  probability density function (positive such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mathrm{d} x = 1$) and $X_0 = \{x_n\}_{1\leq n \leq N}$ be $N$ given real points. We also fix $1 \leq P \leq N$ an integer.

For $X$ a subset of $X_0$ of size $P$, we set
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{P} \sum_{x_0 \in X} g(x-x_0),$$
where $g$ is a Gaussian of mean $0$ and variance $1$.

We consider the following optimisation problem:
$$\min_{X \subset X_0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f (x) - f_X(x) \rvert \mathrm{d} x.$$

This means that we aim at approximating $f(x)$ optimally with a density of the form $f_X$, the challenge being to adequately select $P$ points among the $N$ that are initially given.

Is there any smart way to tackle such optimization task?

NB: $g$ can be changed for any other density if the problem is easier to solve.

Comment: My starting point would be evenly distributed quantiles:  the solutions to either $CDF(x_0)=i/(P+1)$ or $CDF(x_0)=(i-1/2)/P$ for $1\le i\le P$.

Comment: Does such approximation make sense?

Comment: @user64494 Yes. It is essentially a combinatorial search problem.

Comment: @Josia Park: Can you kindly base your claim? I mean sense from probability theory viewpoint.

Comment: The functional to be minimized is of the form $\int |\frac{1}{P} \sum \limits_{i} (f(x)-g(x-x_i))| dx$ where $x_i$ are chosen without replacement from the set $X_0$. Optimization problems where functions are sampled without replacement are well motivated problems, see: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fed5/9dcaa30c7848ca4d587f000f4d291057d582.pdf

Comment: @Josiah Park: Thank you. However, the linked paper is far away (likely, even aside) from the problem under consideration.

Comment: @user64494, Agreed. All that is being said is that some reasons for choosing without replacement functions are present in the paper, albeit some may be specific to the problem considered there.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to reformulate the problem as an *integer convex optimization problem*.

For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_N)$, let $g_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{1}{P} \sum_i \lambda_i g(x - x_i)$.  Now consider $V : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
  V : \lambda \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} | f(x) - g_{\lambda}(x) | \, dx
$$

The function $V$ is convex, and the desired solution is the integer lattice minimizer of $V$ subject to the constraints $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq 1$ and $\sum_i \lambda_i = P$.  Techniques exist to minimize convex functions on a convex domain in the integer lattice by reformulating as an integer linear programming problem with added slack variables.

This approach has the advantages of being general (it will work for any choice of the approximating distribution $g$ for instance) and of being supported by various mature software packages, but it has the disadvantage that it doesn't make much use of the specifics of the problem in question.